# A equation $A/B=A/C\oplus C/B$, where A, B and C are the infinite linear vector space with scalar field R

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Let X, Y and Z be the infinite linear vector space with scalar field C(complex number) and $X\supset Z\supset Y$. Is this equation correct : $X/Y=X/Z\oplus Z/Y$, where X/Y is a quotient space.

**I think a infinite linear vector space with scalar C is a left C-module. So by the third isomorphism theorem, the equation holds.**

Is there anything wrong in my viewpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field all modules over $\mathbb{C}$ are projective. Hence 
$$
E/F=G \implies E\cong F\oplus G\tag{1}
$$
By third isomorphism theorem
$$
(X/Y)/(Z/Y)\cong X/Z\tag{2}
$$
Composing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$
X/Y\cong  X/Z\oplus Z/Y
$$

Comment: I suppose that the (1), you mention, is always true ?

Comment: it is always true for modules over field

Comment: What about the modules is not over the field? Is (1) still true? the projective implies what?

Comment: If $R$ is not a field, then it is not true in general that every $R$-module is projective. Moreover implication $(1)$ in general doesn't hold. Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$ as modules over ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, thought $\mathbb{Z}\not{\cong}2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @Insomnia, if you are glad with this answer you can accept it by clicking checkmark under votes count

Comment: but where is the checkmark button?

Comment: @Insomnia,  see this discussion http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287

Comment: There is no reason to apologize, it is better to accept answers in order to have less opened questions here.